# How does one suggest tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'd like to continue to help with the site, and one of the things I see are tag synonymous lurking around the site. Such as alien and aliens? How does one go about suggesting them?

Answer (score 4):

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

If you don't have permission, then ask a mod in chat or just post in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The tags [science-fiction-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-history) & [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) seem redundant; I’d propose [genre-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-history) to cover the topic.

Comment: There's a discussion on this [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/duplicate-history-tags).